# Visual Studio Setup Package Upgrade

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, updates, visual-studio-setup-proje

I have created an installer package using VS 2010. The setup is working fine.
It includes a msi package file and an external config file.

When I run the installer, and if the software is previously installed, instead of upgrading it, can we just change the config file?

If yes, how ? Please suggest

Regards,
Gagan

Answer (score 0):

How did the config file get copied to the system in the first place?

If it was with custom action code then what *might* work is a repair of the existing installed product. If the CA condition allows it, then the code will be called again and do another copy of the new file.

Otherwise the answer is no. The supported upgrade in a VS-generated MSI is a RemovePreviousVersions major upgrade.

If I knew in advance that updating the config file separate from the product was going to be a requirement, and it's used by an installed application, then I'd make it app's responsibility to have a choice to load a new config file. By tying the config update to an MSI file the design effectively limits the update choices to what's available in VS setup project updates (RemovePreviousVersions).

Comment: The config file has property PackageAs = "vsdpaLoose" , which keeps the config file outside the msi package.

Comment: But still installed by the MSI, registered by the MSI, repaired by the MSI, all the things you don't want if you plan to replace it. It must be truly separate and not managed by the MSI if you plan to replace it in a non-MSI way. Outside the MSI does not mean "not managed by Windows Installer".